# How to set Viewport for depending on iphone & ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari, viewport

I'm working on a website which actually needs to have different viewport settings for ipad and one for iphone. Of course, I've used the known viewport meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">` (ipad viewport)

Now I need to set a different viewport setting for iphone, any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Safari Developer Library Guide: Configuring the Viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW1) has good insight for different viewports but not specifically for iPad.  This solution is from a related [quora question](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-specify-a-different-meta-viewport-for-the-iPad-and-the-iPhone).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no  
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')){ ?>
,width=device-width <?php } else { ?>,initial-scale=0.9 <?php } ?> ">
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.